# Gallow Bracket for Hammock Chair?

Tags: brackets, tree, swing

I have a tree in my backyard with no branches low enough for a chair hammock. My plan is to make a 36" gallow shelf bracket with a 2x4 (hang it upside down so flat part is parallel to the ground), attach it to the tree with 2 lag bolts, reinforce it around the trunk with ratchet straps and then hang the chair from the upside-down bracket using an eye bolt. Now the big money question: Will I end up flat on my ass? Do you think that this will support the the max weight of the hammock (300lb) or even my weight (140lb).
Thanks yall!

Comment: Are you open to the idea of plywood triangles sandwiching the 2x4s? I think that would be way stronger. And while 2 lags might work, my gut says 3 or 4 - 3/8" or bigger, with washers, 8" long. Kinda confused about the merit of the ratchet straps... either the bracket stays up with normal mechanical attachment or it doesn't. Leaving straps out in the sun over time isn't a good strategy.

Comment: A sketch of what you're planning would be most helpful. Especially since you say the "flat part is parallel to the ground" - I'm reading that you'll be putting a 2x4 with the wider, 4" face toward the ground and that is _not_ the strongest direction for a 2x4. Of course, I may be misreading, and that's where the drawing would come in handy.